# How to rewrite code to new unboxed closures

Tags: rust, rust-obsolete

Can somebody help me to rewrite this piece of code with new unboxed closures:

```
struct Builder;
pub fn build(rules: |params: &mut Builder|) -> Builder {
    let mut builder = Builder::new();
    rules(&mut builder);

    builder
}
```

I tried to write like this, but I got a lifetime error:

```
pub fn build<F>(rules: F) -> Builder where F: FnOnce<(&mut Builder,), ()> {
    let mut builder = Builder::new();
    rules(&mut builder);

    builder
}

valico/src/builder.rs:48:59: 48:71 error: missing lifetime specifier [E0106]
valico/src/builder.rs:48     pub fn build<F>(rules: F) -> Builder where F: FnOnce<(&mut Builder,), ()> {
                                                                                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~
```

What lifetime I need to specify? [Simplified example in the sandbox](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=863634b2fd5af9693dc2f172fec7f64f).

Comment: Close-voter: why is this offtopic?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This requires [higher rank trait bounds](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/0387-higher-ranked-trait-bounds.md), specifically, higher rank lifetimes. The full unsugared syntax would be `F: for<'a> FnOnce<(&'a mut Builder,), ()>`.

Using a lifetime on the function can't work, e.g. if we had

```
pub fn build<'b, F>(rules: F) -> Builder where F: FnOnce<(&'b mut Builder,), ()>
```

This says that `build` works with whatever lifetime the caller wishes (e.g. they could chose `'b` == `'static`), but this is invalid, because there is a specific concrete lifetime that needs to be the used: the lifetime of the `&mut builder` inside the function. Using `F: for<'a> ...` in a bound says that `F` works with any lifetime `'a`, so the compiler sees that it is legal to substitute in the one of `&mut builder`.

As I hinted above, that's the really ugly unsugared syntax. There's two successive ways this can be made much nicer. Firstly, the canonical way to use the closure traits is the `()` sugar: `for<'a> FnOnce(&'a mut Builder) -> ()`, or, like with the rest of Rust, the `-> ()` can be dropped: `for<'a> FnOnce(&'a mut Builder)`. (NB. this is just sugar for `FnOnce<...>`, but only the sugared syntax will be stabilised for interacting with these traits at 1.0.)

Then, the paren syntax has a little extra rule: it automatically inserts lifetimes that act like `for<'a>` (specifically, it undergoes [lifetime elision](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/0141-lifetime-elision.md) with any inserted lifetime placed into a `for` on the trait), so just `F: FnOnce(&mut Builder)` is equivalent to `F: for<'a> FnOnce(&'a mut Builder)`, and it's the recommended version.

Applying these fixes to your playpen example:

```
pub fn initialize_with_closure<F>(rules: F) -> uint where F: FnOnce(&mut uint) {
    let mut i = 0;
    rules(&mut i);

    i
}

// equivalently
pub fn initialize_with_closure_explicit<F>(rules: F) -> uint where F: for<'a> FnOnce(&'a mut uint) -> () {
    let mut i = 0;
    rules(&mut i);

    i
}

pub fn main() {
    initialize_with_closure(|i: &mut uint| *i = *i + 20);
    initialize_with_closure_explicit(|i: &mut uint| *i = *i + 20);
}
```

[playpen](http://play.rust-lang.org/?code=pub%20fn%20initialize_with_closure%3CF%3E%28rules%3A%20F%29%20-%3E%20uint%20where%20F%3A%20FnOnce%28%26mut%20uint%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20mut%20i%20%3D%200%3B%0A%20%20%20%20rules%28%26mut%20i%29%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20i%0A%7D%0A%2F%2F%20equivalently%0Apub%20fn%20initialize_with_closure_explicit%3CF%3E%28rules%3A%20F%29%20-%3E%20uint%20where%20F%3A%20for%3C%27a%3E%20FnOnce%28%26%27a%20mut%20uint%29%20-%3E%20%28%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20mut%20i%20%3D%200%3B%0A%20%20%20%20rules%28%26mut%20i%29%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20i%0A%7D%0A%0Apub%20fn%20main%28%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20initialize_with_closure%28%7Ci%3A%20%26mut%20uint%7C%20*i%20%3D%20*i%20%2B%2020%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20initialize_with_closure_explicit%28%7Ci%3A%20%26mut%20uint%7C%20*i%20%3D%20*i%20%2B%2020%29%3B%0A%7D%0A)