# Storing a closure in a HashMap

Tags: rust

To learn the Rust language, I'm taking an old C++ library I had lying around and trying to convert it to Rust. It used a lot of C++11 closures and I'm having some difficulty getting the concepts to translate.

In C++ I had something like this:

```
// library.h
struct Event {
    // just some data
};

class Object {
public:
    // ...
    std::function<void(Event&)>& makeFunc(std::string& s) {
        return m_funcs[s];
    }
    // ...
private:
    // ...
    std::map<std::string, std::function<void(Event&)>> m_funcs;
    // ...
};

// main.cpp using the library
int main()
{
    Object foo;
    foo.makeFunc("func1") = [&]{
        // do stuff
    };
    return 0;
}
```

The part that I'm having trouble with is properly storing the functions in a Rust HashMap collection. I tried this:

```
struct Event;

struct Object {
    m_funcs : HashMap<String, FnMut(&Event)>
}

impl Object {
    // send f as another parameter rather than try and return borrow
    // compiler was complaining
    fn makeFunc(&mut self, s : &str,f: FnMut(&Event)) {
        self.m_funcs.insert(String::from_str(s), f); 
    }
}
```

but it says `the trait core::marker::Sized is not implemented for the type 'for('r) core::ops::FnMut(&'r CreateEvent)'`

This makes sense because `FnMut` is a trait, and therefore has no known size for the HashMap to make at compile time. So I figure that the hashmap would require an actual pointer rather than an abstract type. So I change it to this

```
struct Object {
    m_funcs : HashMap<String, Box<FnMut(&Event)>>
}

impl Object {
    fn makeFunc(&mut self, s : &str, f: &FnMut(&Event)) {
        self.m_funcs.insert(String::from_str(s), Box::new(f));
    }
}
```

now it says `the trait 'for('r) core::ops::Fn<(&'r CreateEvent,)>' is not implemented for the type '&for('r) core::ops::FnMut(&'r CreateEvent)' [E0277]` at the insert. This error makes no sense to me at all. Can someone explain to me the proper way to store a reference to a non-escaping closure in a HashMap?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have taken a `&FnMut(&Event)`—a trait object—and, after boxing it, wish to store it as a `Box<FnMut(&Event)>`. Thus, you require that `&FnMut(&Event)` must implement `FnMut(&Event)`, which it does not (and clearly cannot, for `FnMut.call_mut` takes `&mut self`).

What you wanted was to take an arbitrary type that *implements* `FnMut(&Event)`—that is, use generics—and take it by value. The signature is thus this:

```rust
fn make_func<F: FnMut(&Event)>(&mut self, s: &str, f: F)
```

It gets a little more complex than this due to lifetimes, however, but what you wish to do with regards to that may vary; [Storing an unboxed closure with a reference arg in a HashMap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27906885/storing-an-unboxed-closure-with-a-reference-arg-in-a-hashmap) has more information on that topic. Here’s what I believe you’re most likely to want:

```rust
struct Object<'a> {
    m_funcs: HashMap<String, Box<FnMut(&Event) + 'a>>,
}

impl<'a> Object<'a> {
    fn make_func<F: FnMut(&Event) + 'a>(&mut self, s: &str, f: F) {
        self.m_funcs.insert(String::from_str(s), Box::new(f));
    }
}
```

You could remove all the `'a` in favour of just a single `+ 'static` bound on `F` if you are happy to not let any of the closures capture references to their environments.

Comment: Now that i've read about it, I understand that this is the correct answer, but it has spawned another question for me here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29202698/how-to-use-a-trait-object-to-refer-to-struct-that-has-generic-methods

Comment: What does the `+` operator do with lifetimes ?

Comment: Found it [this related thing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42028470/why-is-adding-a-lifetime-to-a-trait-with-the-plus-operator-iteratoritem-foo) during my journey